# Internationalization in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, action

Any one explain, how flex is support Internationalization and how to use it in flex mxml or actions cript?

Please explain with example.

Thanks,
Ravu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some good places to start from:

[Internationalization in Flex](http://flexme.wordpress.com/2007/07/11/internationalization-in-flex/)

[Runtime Localization](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/Flex_3:Feature_Introductions:_Runtime_Localization)